# I´m starting a video detection software

Tags: windows, video, startup, video-capture, video-processing

I´m thinking on creating a software that can detect some polygons on videos and its movement. Something like: I've got a video focusing a white wall, then I record some shapes moving (triangles, circles, squares) and I want to detect the movement of just triangles, like marking them on the screen.

Having that background said, I don´t need the software done, I just want some help on what tools do I have to use to develop that.

I've got experience on desktop and web programming, but this video recognizing is new for me.

Any guides or tools that would help me?

Thanks!

Comment: The first tool you should be using is called Google... your question is off-topic for SO

Answer (score 0):

Dont have enough reputation to comment. Your question cannot really be answerred directly. You first need access to the pixels of the decoded video frames before you do any "recognition" stuff or similar.

1) What is your video input and do you have any software that provides decoded frames, color space conversion and related stuff from your input?

2) Does your software from point (1) support the programming language you want to develop your detection algorithms?

If you do not care at all about performance, you could possibly use FFmpeg to extract every single image as RGB BMP to disk (or memory) so you can just go ahead with your detection software and work directly on the pixels.

Another related tip and completely different approach is to get started with MATLAB software (use for OpenCV library), that's how some students I know learned about this area.

Comment: Thank you so much, That was very helpful. That's something I can start exploring with.

Comment: I tried to give you a point up but I think I´m too new for it.